# Buttons onClick method restarts if clicked to fast

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I have little application where you can tell your fortune (it's actualy just random), there are four edittextfields that you can type in and one button that choose one of the edittextfields, and remove it. Pretty simple. But i have problem, if someone presses the button multiple times too fast then all of the code in the onClick() method doesn't execute (probably because it is called again). Is there some way that I can prevent this from happening (I want all of the code in the onClick() method to execute before it can be called again)?

Here is the code:

```
    package com.foretell.lukas.spamedprick;

    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<EditText> tfa = new ArrayList<EditText>();

int x = 0;

boolean tf = true;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // References to XML widgets

    final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);

    final Button daButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button restartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restartButton);

    final EditText ruta1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText ruta2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText ruta3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText ruta4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    final TextView outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);

    tfa.add(ruta1);
    tfa.add(ruta2);
    tfa.add(ruta3);
    tfa.add(ruta4);

    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.spar);
    final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hurra);

    daButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(tf) {
                        daButton.setEnabled(false);
                        mp.start();

                        try {
                            tf = false;
                            Thread.sleep(2000);

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.getStackTrace();
                            outputText.setText("Nått gick åt h***ete!");
                        }



                        Collections.shuffle(tfa);


                        x++;

                        if (x <= 2) {

                            outputText.setText("Det är inte " + tfa.get(0).getText() + "...");
                            tfa.get(0).setText("");
                            tfa.remove(0);

                        } else if (x == 3) {

                            outputText.setText("Det är...");

                        } else if (x == 4) {

                            tfa.get(1).setText("");
                            tfa.remove(1);
                            outputText.setText("Det är " + tfa.get(0).getText() + "!");
                            mp2.start();

                        }

                        tf = true;
                        daButton.setEnabled(true);

                    }else{
                        System.out.println("YO!");
                    }

                }

            }


    );

    restartButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    tfa.add(ruta1);
                    tfa.add(ruta2);
                    tfa.add(ruta3);
                    tfa.add(ruta4);

                    ruta1.requestFocus();

                    outputText.setText("");

                    x = 0;

                    ruta1.setText("");
                    ruta2.setText("");
                    ruta3.setText("");
                    ruta4.setText("");

                }
            }



    );

}


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can first disable the button (button.setEnabled(false)), do the work on onClickListener and in the end enable the button again (button.setEnabled(true)).
Hope this will help you.

Comment: I was going to write the same thing. Just disable and enable the button

Comment: Even I was going to write the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that an "onClick" can be started before the last "onClick" is finished.

Here is the qoute from the android documentation:

> The system does not create a separate thread for each instance of a component. All components that run in the same process are instantiated in the UI thread, and system calls to each component are dispatched from that thread. Consequently, methods that respond to system callbacks (such as onKeyDown() to report user actions or a lifecycle callback method) always run in the UI thread of the process.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Maybe you do something in the onClick method, that makes trouble, but without the code it is hard to tell:)

Comment: Do not use Thread.sleep, mediaplayer has a callback if the playback is finished. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html. Disable the button as the others said and enable it after the callback is called.

Comment: But I want that for effect, This is an app that is meant to tell your fortune, and the sleep thing makes the user think that a wizard or something is thinking

Comment: The point is that dont enable the button at the end of the "onclick", but at the end of the fortune telling. When eveything is set and finished. Callbacks can be the solution.

Comment: But all of the "fortune telling" code is in the onClick method so there is no other place to put setEnabled argument in.

Comment: mp.start() is asynchron, you have to wait the end of the media playback with this callback: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) after that (and the end of your code) enable the button again.

Comment: What shall I have in the OnCompletion callback?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       button.setEnabled(false);

        // do your work here
      // make it true after your work is done 
       button.setEnabled(true);

    }
});
```

Comment: I also thougth that this would do it but for some reason it doesn't quite work.